VS Code Port Forwarding not working on .NET Aspire projects
The VS Code port forwarding feature does not work for my .NET Aspire projects. I'm busy building a new project, that I tried performing the forwarding on. Requests to the dev tunnel load for a bit before returning a 400 status code.
I've confirmed that the ports configured in launchSettings.json are the ones I'm attempting to forward. Below is my configuration:

I've also tried doing this on the default Aspire Starter project template but get the same results.
I created a new Blazor Server project - same as what Aspire has in the Starter project - and I'm able to set up port forwarding without issue.
I've read through the .NET Aspire inner-loop networking overview documentation but nothing stands out of what I might be doing wrong. My understanding is that forwarding the port that the Aspire Proxy is listening on, should send requests down to the project.
Has anyone tried setting this up or ran into this issue before?
